# Installing aria2 on OS X using Homebrew fails

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have been a Linux user for a long time now mainly using Debian based systems. Recently I also bought a 15" MacBooK Pro with Retina Display and now, I am trying to install my lovely command line tools using Homebrew on it.

I have been successful so far, until now that I tried to install `aria2` which failed. Here's what happened:

```
Akos-MacBook-Pro:tmp ako$ brew install aria2
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/aria2/stable/aria2-1.18.0/aria2-1.18.0.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/aria2-1.18.0.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/aria2/1.18.0 --with-ca-bundle=/usr/local/share/ca-bundle.crt --without-appletls
==> make install
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [LibgmpDHKeyExchange.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting

Akos-MacBook-Pro:tmp ako$
```

I think the error has something to do with the certificates(crt file).
Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the problem.

I removed all the files belonging to `Homebrew` and did a fresh re-install of `Homebrew` first.
Then I installed `aria2` and it went fine.